# Simulink C-Code Generationed logic

Tags: c, simulink, generated-code

simple question here. I would like to examine the generated c code after it has been generated from Simulink. The problem is, I cannot find any of the logic code, or variables from the model. I've looked through the internet for a solution, but there's nothing that really points me in the right direction. Can anybody elaborate on what kind of structure is used when creating auto-generated c code from Simulink? I'd like to look at how the actual logic was created. I made a simple comparison model with three inputs and an or block, and a to-workspace block. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for. Are you unable to find the place where the actual "or" is evaluated? Maybe replace it with some other operation which is easier to track, for example a multiplication with 123456. You will find probably only one such operation.

Comment: Yes, I can't find where the or statement is evaluated.